# Array not printing what it should be - android

Tags: android, listview

When I try print the values to a textfield they come out as [Ljava.lang.String;@405af10

```
try {
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());

    JSONArray Monday = jObject.getJSONArray("Monday");

    String time = "";
    String module = "";
    String lecturer = "";

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(this, R.layout.simplerow);


    for (int i = 0; i < Monday.length(); i++) 
    {
        time = Monday.getJSONObject(i).getString("time");
        module = Monday.getJSONObject(i).getString("module");
        lecturer = Monday.getJSONObject(i).getString("lecturer");

        listAdapter.add(new String[] {time, module, lecturer});

    }
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);    

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in the simplerow xml file I have

```
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

So each time a time, module or lecturer is printed it should be in it's own textview box., but it's not working and I don't know why or how to fix it.

Comment: How is it 'not working'? Is it crashing?  Showing the wrong thing, if so, how is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely because your `ArrayAdapter` is set to accept in a `String` array (`String []`).

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(this, R.layout.simplerow); //Parameterized for String []
```

Therefore you have a list of `String` arrays, which is basically equivalent to a 2D array.

This means, when the `ArrayAdapter` is setting the Text to the TextView you specified, it is calling `toString()` on the whole array object, hence the hashcode.

Consider making your own `ArrayAdapter` and override the `getView()` method so that it does what you want to do. There are plenty of tutorials online, such as [this](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/) one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that has worked perfectly! A few little things left to finish off.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make a POJO to hold your data. The POJO can have a name such as `CourseInfo` which clearly defines its meaning. Similarly, the members of `CourseInfo` will clearly define what they represent. This is preferred to an array because you can clearly define the meaning of each piece of data. Typically, Java programmers frown upon using an array which holds heterogenous data. In this case, even though the type of each piece of data is the same, the meaning of each element of the array differs.

This solution has the advantage that you can change

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(this, R.layout.simplerow);
```

to

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CourseInfo>(this, R.layout.simplerow);
```